# How to activate an account after user has clicked on the activation link?

Tags: php, mysqli

Thanks to a [youtube tutorial from Nickfrosty](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y2NYbEjTzE8) on being able to create a proper registration system in php, I have been able to convert his code from [mysql](https://www.mysql.com/) to [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) and was able to send an activation link by email after the user has registered.

Below is the code where it inserts the registration details in the database and sends the message and activation link to the user's email after the user has registered.

```
$code = md5(rand());

$insertsql = "
INSERT INTO Teacher
(TeacherForename, TeacherSurname, TeacherEmail, TeacherAlias, TeacherUsername, TeacherPassword, Code)
VALUES
(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
";
if (!$insert = $mysqli->prepare($insertsql)) {
// Handle errors with prepare operation here
}                                           

$insert->bind_param("sssssss", $getfirstname, $getsurname,
$getemail, $getid, $getuser,
$teacherpassword, $code);

$insert->execute();

if ($insert->errno) {
// Handle query error here
}

$insert->close();

$site = "http://helios.hud.ac.uk/......../Mobile_app";
$webmaster = "Mayur Patel <.......@hud.ac.uk>";
$headers = "From: $webmaster";
$subject = "Activate Your Account";
$message = "Thanks for Registering. Click the link below to Acivate your Account. \n";
$message .= "$site/activate.php?user=$getuser&code=$code\n";
$message .= "You must Activate your Account to Login";

if(mail($getemail, $subject, $message, $headers)){
$errormsg = "You have been Registered. You must Activate your Account from the Activation Link sent to <b>$getemail</b>";
$getfirstname = "";
$getsurname = "";
$getid = "";
$getuser = "";
$getemail = "";
}
```

But I have an issue now. If I click on the link, it navigates the user to the `activate.php` page.

My question is: after the user has clicked on the activation link, how does it activate the user's account? I need it to be able to recognize the user's username and activation code by looking it up in the php above `$message .= "$site/activate.php?user=$getuser&code=$code\n";` and then in the database I need it to update the `Active` column for that user from `0 to`1`, so that the user is now active. Is the below statement correct:

```
"UPDATE Teacher SET Active='1' WHERE TeacherUsername = '$getuser'"
"SELECT * FROM Teacher WHERE TeacherUsername='$getuser' AND Active='1'"
```

The `activate.php` page simply displays a message, stating that account is activated. If user has already been activated, then I want it to display message stating user has already been activated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I'd code the activate.php :

Code :

```
$sUser = $_GET['username'];
$sCode = $_GET['code'];

//MYPRIVATEKEY defined on a conf.php or else
$sEncodedUser = hash_hmac('sha1', $sUser, 'MYPRIVATEKEY');

if($sEncodedUser == $sUser) {
    $sQuery = "UPDATE USER SET activated=1 WHERE USERNAME = " . escape($sUser);
    //RUN $sQuery;
    echo 'Account activated !';
} else {
    echo 'Problem when activating your account';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you not to use the TeacherUserName to SELECT your teacher.

Your table should contain a column TEACHER_ID (int, auto_increment) : imagine if two teachers have the same name ?

Suppose teachers have different names, you can create a secure code with the hash_hmac function :

```
$code = hash_hmac('sha1', 'username', 'YOUR_SECRET_KEY');
```

You can :

1. generate this code when your sending your email (name='Tom', code='ARI3428UZE')
2. when the user click on the link, you just have to get the username (name = 'Tom'), create the code one more time (newcode = 'ARI3428UZE') with hash_mac
3. you test code == newcode
4. if the two codes are the same, you can update your table as you propose

The best way is to use a TEACHER_ID instead of the TEACHERNAME.

Comment: I have teacherId which is auto increment but I will use TeacherUsername because no teacher can have the same username. I will try this out and see what happens. Cheers

Comment: If yo don't mind fabrice, to make it easier, can you show me how you would code the activate.php page so that I can see what needs to be done? Im in no rush, but if I can see how you would code it, it would really give me a head start and then I can use and manipulate the code to be able to get it working in my application.

Answer (score 0):

When Registering:

Create a variable $random = rand(1,9); <-- To get a random number.
Insert this in the table when registering with the other values like Teacher Alies, Teacher Surname.

Send an email to his email address. With the code attached in his email link.

```
www.yourdomain.com/activate.php?username=teachername&code=randomcodehere
```

Put this in activate.php

```
$user_to_be_activated       =   $_GET['username'];
$code_to_be_matched     =   $_GET['codehere'];

$query      =   mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Teacher WHERE teachername='$user_to_be_activated' AND activecode='$code_to_be_matched'");
$counting   =   mysql_num_rows($query);

if($counting    ==  '1')
{
    mysql_query("UPDATE Teacher SET accountactive='1'"); <-- Set this to 0 when registering
}
else
{
    echo"The code and Username doesn't match!";
}
```

So when he clicks the verification email, Your website would check the username and the code from database, If they are correct then set the activate to 1.I know there are allot of code errors in there and needs to be corrected and modified, But I am a new developer, This should have given you the hint to do it, Thanks.